# How to parse JSON file with multiple objects

Tags: python, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file which is containing multiple JSON objects. Here is my code:

```
{
    "obj1": {
        "type": "object", 
        "permission": "r",
        "obj2": {
            "type": "param", 
            "permission": "r/w"
        }, 
        "obj3": {
            "type": "param", 
            "permission": "r"
        }, 
        "obj4": {
            "type": "object", 
            "permission": "r",
            "obj5": {
                "type": "param", 
                "permission": "r/w"
            }, 
            "obj6": {
                "type": "param", 
                "permission": "r"
            },
            "obj7": {
                "type": "object", 
                "permission": "r",
                "obj8": {
                    "type": "param", 
                    "permission": "r/w"
                }, 
                "obj9": {
                    "type": "param", 
                    "permission": "r"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had tried single object parsing response in JSON, that I able to fetch. But I don't not know how to parse the JSON object with Multiple nodes.

For each JSON obejct , I don't also know its name (obj1, obj2, ..)

I want in output as result:

```
obj1: has 2 param and 1 object
obj2: has 2 param and 1 object
obj3: has 2 param
```

Is there any way with python to parse JSON file with multiple objects?

Comment: `json.loads(json_string)` will return you python `dict`. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
op = json.loads(json_string)
for i,(key,value) in enumerate(op.items()):
    objects = 0
    params = len(value)
    if isinstance(value,dict):
        for k,v in value.items():
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                objects +=1



    print("Object {i} has {params} params and {objects} objects".format(i=i+1,params=params-objects,objects=obj
```